# OData over EntityFramework - Querying xml column data

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework, odata

I'm using *OData* over *Entity Framework 6*.

Querying is pretty straight forward when it comes to columns, but I need to perform some deep querying over xml data columns.

If I would query my *SQL* table using *TSQL*, I would probably use the [value()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type) method.

I couldn't get this working with the default OData implementation and I also see that EntityFramework has no idea my column is an xml column (It's a string and I see no support for xml) so I guess this wont work out of the box.

Questions:

1. Any chance this does work out of the box? If so, can you please provide an example?
2. Is there an way I can create something custom? I guess I would need to somehow custom translate the query string and somehow create proper Expression Trees to make things work.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?